# preg_replace_callback BB code multiple instances

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I'm currently developing a forum. In the threads, I want the user to be able to quote other posts in their own post. It is working so far, the only problem I have is with quotes inside quotes.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[quote=([^]]+);([0-9]+)\]([^]]+)\[\/quote\]/i', function($matches){

   // Include MySQLi into function
   global $DB;

   $get = $DB->query("SELECT quote.date, quote.text, user.username FROM forum AS quote INNER JOIN users AS user ON quote.userid = user.id WHERE quote.id = '".beforeDB($matches[2])."'");
   $row = $get->fetch_array();

   if($get->num_rows == 0)
      return "";

   $return = '
   <div class="box table">
   <table width="100%">
    <tr style="height: 22px;"><td style="width: 122px; background: #e8e8e8;"><div style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 5px; '.(userColor($row['username']) != false ? 'color: '.userColor($row['username']).';' : '').'">'.$row['username'].'</div></td><td style="background: #e8e8e8; padding-left: 5px;">'.dateFunction($row['date'], true, true, true).'</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #efefef; padding: 3px;">'.$row['text'].'</td></tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   ';

   return $return;

  }, $text); 
?>
```

This is, as I said earlier, working. The forum table is storing both posts and threads.

If I write this in a post however, it does not work:

```
[quote=Admin;1]Hi guys![/quote]

[quote=Admin;1]Hi guys!

[quote=Mod;3]Whats up?[/quote][/quote]
```

With the BB codes above, the first and second quote is working. However, the quotes within the quote is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can build a recursive function that replace only the innermost quote tag until there are no more quote tags to replace.

Comment: Here is one way to to get the innermost (or last) quote tag [`~.*\K\[quote=([^;]+);(\d+)\].*?\[/quote\]~is`](http://regex101.com/r/dQ5wR3)

Comment: Tried your regex, Sam. Unfortunately, it does not work with all quotes (I guessed as much). About the recursive function: I've tried, but it does not seem to work. The preg_replace_callback function within the function does not execute more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure from your post what you are looking for, but maybe you can use something like this to get the contents in between the quote tags.

```
~\[quote=.*?\](.*)\[/quote\]~i
```

This will return:

```
Whats up?[/quote]
```

This should work for single instances of the pattern, however if you can have multiple instances, you would probably want to include a negative lookahead to make sure that `[/quote]` does not appear directly after a `[/quote]`.

```
~\[quote=.*?\].*?\[/quote\](?!\[/quote\])~i
```

[Here is an example for you to tinker around with.](http://ideone.com/zgntrh)

I guess this would work if you have a string like `[/quote][/quote]` but it wouldn't work if you had something in between those tags. `[/quote] sdf [/quote]`.  So that's why I added the link to strip out any left over `[/quote]` tags.

Hopefully something like that is what you were after.